# Usar createQueryBuilder do Doctrine com tablelas que não possuem entidade

Tags: php, doctrine-2, symfony

É possível realizar uma consulta com o createQueryBuilder do Doctrine utilizando uma tabela que não tem uma entidade declarada (Entity)?

Exemplo:
No código abaixo a tabela table2 (t2) não possui uma entidade criada, por ser uma tabela de relacionamento e só possuir os campos de relação.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('t1')
     ->select(['t1', 't2.id'])
     ->leftJoin('table2', 't2', 'ON', 't1.id = t2.id')
     ->andWhere('t2.id IS NOT NULL')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```

Comment: Quando é relacionamento tu nem precisa fazer uma query custom, só dar um get da propriedade na entity. Mas se por algum motivo for necessário tu precisa é só bota na select pra retornar t1.t2 ( onde t2 é o nome da propriedade na entity t1).

Answer (score 0):

> É possível realizar uma consulta com o createQueryBuilder do Doctrine utilizando uma tabela que não tem uma entidade declarada (Entity)?

Sim é possivel se utilizares DBAL. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/index.html